# How do you color lines that begin with string1 but do not end with string2

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed, grep

I run a weekly crontab that collects information and creates a log file.

I have a script that I run against this weekly file to output only specific status lines to my display.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# store newest filename to variable
HW_FILE="$(ls -t /home/user/hwinfo/|head -1)"

# List the Site name, hardware group, Redundancy or Health status', and the site divider
grep -i 'Site\|^\*\*\|^Redundancy\|^Health\|^##' /home/user/hwinfo/$HW_FILE
echo "/home/user/hwinfo/"$HW_FILE
exit 0
```

This is a sample output:

```
Accessing Site: site01
** FANS **
Redundancy Status : Full
** MEMORY **
Health : Ok
** CPUs **
Health : Ok
** POWER SUPPLIES **
Redundancy Status : Full
##########################################
Accessing Site: site02
** FANS **
Redundancy Status : Full
** MEMORY **
Health : Degraded
** CPUs **
Health : Ok
** POWER SUPPLIES **
Redundancy Status : Full
##########################################
Accessing Site: site03
** FANS **
Redundancy Status : Failed
** MEMORY **
Health : Ok
** CPUs **
Health : Ok
** POWER SUPPLIES **
Redundancy Status : Full
##########################################
/home/user/hwinfo/hwinfo_102217_034001.txt
```

Is there a way to cat / grep / sed / awk / perl / the current output so that any lines that begin with either `Redundancy` or `Health`, but don't end in `Full` or `Ok`, respectively, get colorized?

What I want to see is this

[image: imgur link]

I've tried piping the current output to `| grep --color=auto \bRedundancy\w*\b(?<!Full)\|\bHealth\w*\b(?<!Ok)` without success. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

With any awk in any shell on any UNIX box:

```
awk -v on="$(tput setaf 1)" -v off="$(tput sgr0)" '$1~/^(Health|Redundancy)$/ && $NF!~/^(Full|Ok)$/{$0 = on $0 off} 1'  file
```

[image]

You should really use a more robust expression with string comparisons though rather than the current loose regexp:

```
awk -v on="$(tput setaf 1)" -v off="$(tput sgr0)" '
(($1=="Health") && ($NF!="Ok")) || (($1=="Redundancy") && ($NF!="Full")) { $0 = on $0 off }
1'  file
```

Comment: Very elegant indeed!

Answer (score 7):

Using GNU grep:

```
| grep -P --color=auto '^Redundancy.*(?<!Full)$|^Health.*(?<!Ok)$|$'
```

-P to use PCRE for lookbehind (which I don't think grep supports otherwise), `|$` to make it output all lines.  You need to use the lookbehind right before the line-end.

Comment: Considering adding `|$` at the end instead of `-C` :)

Comment: @PesaThe clever

Comment: You should mention that'll only work with GNU grep and that according to the maintainers `-P` is "highly experimental" (see the man page) so YMMV with using it. It has been known to quit with a core dump.